# Object Variable or with block variable not set. Code suddenly put on the error

Tags: excel, vba

Please let me know the error in this code. It was working fine a few hours ago and suddenly started giving error

> "Object Variable or with block variable not set"

```
'
' Find Macro
'

'
Dim rw As Integer
rw = 1

 Do Until IsEmpty(Sheet2.Cells(rw, 1))
    Cells.Find(What:=Sheet2.Cells(rw, 1)).Activate

         On Error GoTo hello


         With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 65535
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0

       Sheet2.Cells(rw, 2).Value = "Found"

hello:          rw = rw + 1
Sheet2.Cells(1, 3) = Sheet2.Cells(1, 3) + 1


      End With
      Loop
MsgBox "Total E-Forms Searched " & Sheet2.Cells(1, 3)
End Sub
```

It is finding data in sheet1 and highlights it yellow. Criteria is in sheet2.

Comment: If your Find fails then the chained Activate will raise an error.  Comment out the `On Error` to see if that's the problem.

Comment: I have tried this but doesn't work. it gives error when Find fails.

Comment: avoid using `ActiveSheet` as well. Incoporate that in @TimWilliams code and try again. also remember `lookat:=xlWhole` will find the whole word. Maybe you want `lookat:=xlPart`?

Comment: I am v greatful for the help. But can anybody point the exact issue in my code. I want to know for my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
Dim c As Range, f As Range

Set c = Sheet2.Cells(1, 1)

Do Until IsEmpty(c)
    Set f = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(What:=c.Value, lookat:=xlWhole)
    'got a match?
    If Not f is nothing then
         'highlight the match
         With f.Interior
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = 65535
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
         End With

         Sheet2.Cells(1, 3) = Sheet2.Cells(1, 3) + 1

         c.offset(0, 1).Value = "Found"
     End if

     Set c = c.offset(1,0) 'next row 
Loop
MsgBox "Total E-Forms Searched " & Sheet2.Cells(1, 3)
```

Comment: Not working. Although it does not give any error but does not perform the desired task too.

Comment: I made a guess you wanted exact match, but maybe that's not the case?  Anyhow, did you try debugging to see what's not working?

Comment: The find portion of code shows error. Can't figure out why.

Comment: Object variable or with block variable not set

Comment: Which exact line?

Comment: ```Cells.Find(What:=Sheet2.Cells(rw, 1)).Activate``` This line is highlighted in error.

Comment: That's not in my code and there's a reason why my code doesn't try to do that, explained in my first comment on your question.